# Load Javascript (in background) without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, angular5, background-process

I have a script that calls a JS file to display some contents and it works only when the page is reloaded, I mean, when I switch between the different pages that I have in my app, I can't see the contents only unless I reload the whole page - that is when it appears again.

I tried to call the script whenever the user switches between the pages but it didn't work.

The easiest way is to reload the page in background.

This is the function that I want to be called

```
loadMyScript(event) {
  this.loadJsFile('myScript.js');
}
```

How can I execute the JS or load the page in background with Angular 5?

Comment: "I have a script that calls a JS file to display some contents and it works only when the page is reloaded" - rewrite it so it works sensibly with your SPA.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample on how you 'tried to call the script'?

Answer (score 0):

You can add script tag with src="..."  on your page body with .insertAdjancentHTML for example. Or you can use AMD.

Also you can try eval but it is BAD PRACTICE

Comment: Please add minimal code examples to make the answer easier to understand.

Comment: is it possible to reload the page on background ?

Answer (score 0):

i am working laravel with vue js. and i need this load js after page load or in background.

so i find this solution hope this will helpful for you.

```
<script>
window.onload=function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
       loadGoogleCaptcha();
    }, 2000); 

}
function loadGoogleCaptcha() {
 var script = document.createElement("script");
 script.src = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js";
 script.type = "text/javascript";
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is that the REFRESH of the whole page is required to make the script shows the data; otherwise, it just calls the script and shows a 200 OK as a response, but what i wanted to do is to reload the page in background, as if we press F5 ^^

Comment: You can do make your request running in background using the webworkers.

Comment: any examples of how to use it ?

Comment: process search on google about web-workers and you get knowledge.